# How to insert 3 biographies with 3 photos stacked on the left in a LaTeX Book Environment?

Tags: tables, columns

For a new book I am writing with two friends, I like to include three biographies (mine as well as the other two friends) after the preface. Ideally, we like to keep three photos (A.jpg, B.jpg and C.jpg) on the left and our biographies on the right.. The book is in single column format, and I don't know how this biographies page can be done in double column format. Also, the biographies need to be aligned with our photos. We are OK with any format or style in a professional way as long as we can post our biographies along with the photos. Your suggestions are most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Just use a `tabular` environment.

Comment: Can you kindly give me the LaTeX commands for this?! I shall try.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See e.g. [How to top align text and image in table?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/124356)

Comment: Dear Alan Munn, the link helped me very much.. I got the formatting right, and I am now adding details. Still I request that we may keep the question in the forum as other authors may also find this exchange useful. Some publishers put the biographies of the authors at the back cover of the book and we are putting it after the Preface .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{12cm}}
        \includegraphics[valign=t,width=2.8cm]{example-image-a} \rotatebox[origin=l]{0}{Rossi Giacomo} & \lipsum[1]\\[1ex]
        \includegraphics[valign=t,width=2.8cm]{example-image-b} \rotatebox[origin=l]{0}{Bianchi Giovanni} & \lipsum[1]\\[1ex]
        \includegraphics[valign=t,width=2.8cm]{example-image-c} \rotatebox[origin=l]{0}{Verdi Alberti} & \lipsum[1]\\[1ex]
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to nice @Raffaele Santoro answer (+1). Differences:

- use is `tabularx` table
- figure are included by `adjincludegraphics` of `adjustbox` package
- defined common style with `\adjustboxset`
- for authors names is used `\captionof*{figure}{<name>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\captionsetup{skip=3pt}
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, keepaspectratio, 
              valign=t, 
              }
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{30mm}X @{}}
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
\captionof*{figure}{Rossi Giacomo}
    &   \lipsum[66] \\
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
\captionof*{figure}{Rossi Giacomo}
    &   \lipsum[66] \\
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
\captionof*{figure}{Rossi Giacomo}
    &   \lipsum[66] \\
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text block border}

Comment: `\captionof*` as a formating tool?  You could achieve the same effect with `\par\vskip3pt\centerline`.  Then again, why not?